# Uncaught Error: Google not defined | Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js

I am working on a small project that works heavily with google maps api. I dont have any errors but the page where the map is supposed to be loading is empty. I think it is because the my location object is being passed and the properties are not being inspected once the object is being passed.

If you know about the gogole maps api and you can help, I would really aprreciate it.

```js
/*----------------list of all the global variables---------------------*/
var map;

/*----------------This is the model---------------------*/
var initialLocation = {
  center:{
    lng: 33.895593,
    lat: -117.316224
  },
  zoom: 15
}

/*----------------This is the viewmodel---------------------*/
function initMap(){
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), initialLocation);
}

/*----------------This is the view---------------------*/
$("googleMap").append(map);
```

```css
html,
.container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

#googleMap{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Omar Jandali Udacity Map</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="collections/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="collections/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="collections/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async defer
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDik_TF3x4yc96CvWWw12YQ4DMjoG3vfFM&v=3&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When `$("googleMap").append(map);` executes, `map` is still set to null. You would need to execute it inside the callback function `initMap()` after `map` has been assigned the map object, e.g.

```
function initMap(){
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), initialLocation);
    $("#googleMap").append(map);
}
```

Comment: also, your jQuery selector is missing a `#` character to indicate id. It should be `$("#googleMap").append(map)`

Comment: I tried that and I messed around a little bit but still nothing. It is blank with no error when i messed around but it is still not loading anything with or without the error

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
function initMap(){
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-117.316224, 33.895593);

var mapOptions = {zoom: 7, center:latlng}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOptions);

}
```